# Creating stripped TableTows in android

Tags: java, android, tablerow

I have created and dynamically added rows to my table layout in android using java. Now I would like to know if it is possible to make the rows stripped like would be done using bootstrap in web pages
i.e this is what I have
[image: Inserted table appearance]
And what I want is something like this
[image: expected table appearance]
Is this possible in android using java or is there a library I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just set alternating background colors on each TableRow.

Also, side not, RecyclerView is almost always the right solution instead of using TableLayout.

Comment: Any links to where I can get the steps on how to use recyckler view instead of table layout?